# How to convert a string to double?

Tags: c#, parsing, double

I need some help with converting.
I want to convert a string to a double so I first did like this.

```
double meterStartvalue = double.Parse(startMeterReading.Text);
```

And this is fine as long as you put something in the textbox. And that is not good. So I tried to do like this:

```
double.TryParse(startMeterReading.Text, out meterStartvalue);
```

When doing the **TryParse** I get this error:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'out meterStartvalue' to 'out double'
>
> The best overloaded method match for 'double.TryParse(string, out
>   double)' has some invalid arguments

Also getting error that the meterStartvelue context does not exist because i use this on some places in the code.

Comment: What is `meterStartvalue` exactly?

Comment: is `startMeterReading.Text` a string? is it a field? is it a method? is it a property?

Comment: Question is not related to windows phone. Removing tag. Feel free to roll-back changes if you think otherwise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to declare `meterStartValue` before you call the method, as otherwise the compiler has no idea what you're talking about:

```
double meterStartValue;
if (double.TryParse(startMeterReading.Text, out meterStartvalue))
{
    // Yes, we managed to parse the text.
}
else
{
    // Failed to parse it
}
```

Note that you *don't* have to give it an initial value; it will be definitely assigned when the method returns though (with a value of 0 if parsing failed).

Unfortunately there's no way of declaring the variable *and* calling the method (using the variable as an argument) in a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

Smells like you forget to declare your `meterStartValue` variable before using it in your code.

Try like this;

```
double meterStartValue;

if (double.TryParse(startMeterReading.Text, out meterStartvalue))
{
    // Success
}
```

Since [`Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx) returns `boolean` you can check if the conversation is succeed or not with an if statement.

```
Return Value
Type: System.Boolean
true if string was converted successfully; otherwise, false.
```